# How to remove custom actions deployed via feature in SharePoint 2010

Tags: feature, custom

I have created a custom action using Element.xml and deployed via Web Application level scope Feature. Now the custom actions are available in almost 3000 sites under that web application. Business wants to remove these custom actions across all sites.

How to remove these existing custom actions from 3000 sites?
Will retracting feature deletes all these custom actions?

OR

Do I need to write a Utility (Poweshell or Object Model Code) to delete these custom actions?

Please suggest to correct approach.

Comment: Do not retract the solution without deactivating the feature as this will create orphan features in your content databases. Use PowerShell to loop through all the site collections in your web application and deactivate the feature, and then uninstall and remove the solution from your farm.

Comment: Christoffer, If I uninstall the feature in all the sites using PS (as you said above), will it remove the existing Custom Actions?

Comment: Yes. If you deactivate the feature, it will remove custom action.